# Extracting pwsafe.key from memory dump

Tags: memory-dump

I am at uni and we have been given coursework to do. This is not asked of us but its something extra i want to try. on the encase image we have been given there is a database.kdb file which i have managed to get the hashes using JTR and retrieving the master key, however to access the keepass file. the key is needed. Now i know the pwsafe.key is locked in the onedrive personal vault with our lectures personal email which we have been told we are not allowed to access, but is there a way that i can extract the key from the memory dump file. the machine is a windows 10 enterprise. can i extract the contents of files opened by the process keepass.exe

any information needed i will happily give